# The React video component doesn't play videos on iOS versions earlier than 17

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, html5-video

I am experiencing unusual behavior with a React video component. Firstly, I want to mention that it works fine on desktop (Windows, Linux, Mac) and mobile (Android, iOS v17). However, for iOS versions prior to 17, my video components does not want to play if muted is set to false.

Maybe someone knows what could be causing this issue?

Here's the component code:

```
<video src={videoUrl} preload={"yes"} muted={mute} autoPlay width="100%" playsInline height="100%"  style={{position: "absolute",top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0,opacity: videoReady ? 1 : 0,zIndex: videoReady ? 30 : 10,}} onLoadedData={() => toggleVideoState(true)}   onEnded={() => toggleVideoState(false)} />
```